# Get unique Index names in elasticsearch

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, spring-data-elasticsearch

Using ES rest client, How to get List of all **unique** index names, based on some search criterion. Below code gives my all index names but duplicate ones too. Please help.

```
SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery(); 

boolQueryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("indexMetadata.user","95103"));
boolQueryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("indexMetadata.indexLevel","LOCAL"));

sourceBuilder.query(boolQueryBuilder);

SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
String[] includeFields = new String[]{"hits.hits._index"};
String[] excludeFields = new String[]{};
sourceBuilder.fetchSource(includeFields, excludeFields);

searchRequest.source(sourceBuilder);

SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest);
        SearchHits hits = searchResponse.getHits();
        SearchHit[] searchHits = hits.getHits();
       for (SearchHit hit : searchHits) {
            System.out.println(hit.getIndex());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [_cat API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-indices.html):

```
GET /_cat/indices
```

It returns all the indexes present in your cluster without duplicates.

Comment: I am using High Level Rest client and i am also applying some filters. Based on that i am trying to get index names. Could you please suggest me the right code snippet for this case